# where is wrong in the sum of series $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came through two types of solutions of the series $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots$
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}\cdot\frac{1}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}\cdot\frac{1}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}x(e^x-1)dx\\
&=\frac{-1}{2}
\end{align*}$$
where am I getting wrong please help!

Comment: Probably that only a constant is supposed to be taken out...?

Comment: $x(e^x-1)$ is positive for $x\in(0,1)$, so the value of your last integral can't be negative.

Comment: Actually, $x(e^x-1)$ integrates to $1/2$, not $-1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\int^{1}_{0}x(e^{x}-1)dx=[e^{x}(x-1)-\frac{x^{2}}{2}]|^{1}_{0}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. The evaluation of the integral is done by the fundamental theorem of calculus:$$ \int_0^1 x \left( \mathrm{e}^x-1\right) \mathrm{d}x = \left. \left(\left(x-1\right) \mathrm{e}^{x} - \frac{x^2}{2} \right)\right|_{x=0}^{x=1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I see. Thanks for notice.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's my mistake. Very sorry to post things like this.